# Creating a Bar Plot with Proportions on ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to create a bar graph on ggplot that has proportions rather than counts, and I have `c+geom_bar(aes(y=(..count..)/sum(..count..)*100))` but I'm not sure what either of the counts refer to. I tried putting in the data but it didn't seem to work. What should I input here?

This is the data I'm using

```
> describe(topprob1)
topprob1 
      n missing  unique    Info    Mean 
    500       0       9    0.93   3.908 

            1   2 3  4  5   6  7  8 9
Frequency 128 105 9 15 13 172 39 12 7
%          26  21 2  3  3  34  8  2 1
```

Answer (score 6):

You haven't provided a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/496488), so here's an illustration with the built-in `mtcars` data frame. Compare the following two plots. The first gives counts. The second gives proportions, which are displayed in this case as percentages. `..count..` is an internal variable that ggplot creates to store the count values.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(am)) +
  geom_bar()

ggplot(mtcars, aes(am)) +
  geom_bar(aes(y=..count../sum(..count..))) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels=percent_format())
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You can also use ..prop.. computed variable with group aesthetics:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(am)) +
  geom_bar(aes(y=..prop.., group = 1)) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels=percent_format())
```

[image]