# I wish to change the variable on the y-axis of my bar graph

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot proportions on the y-axis of my bar graph, as opposed to the usual count.

I am doing something like the following:

```r
ggplot(data=mpg, aes(model))+geom_bar(aes(y=stat(count/sum(count)))
```

I am getting a blank plot.

Comment: Dear Student, please make your question [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: Why do you need `table`, can you show an image of your expected plot?

Comment: Don't use `$` inside `aes` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32543340/issue-when-passing-variable-with-dollar-sign-notation-to-aes-in-combinatio

Comment: @NelsonGon I'm changing my code accordingly. I got a partial answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36604127/creating-a-bar-plot-with-proportions-on-ggplot

But it still isn't working.

Comment: I don't get it: you had a reproducible example, and now you've edited it so you no longer do. Without having your data, it's difficult to do more than guess

Comment: I apologise, have made it reproducible.

Comment: You're missing a closing parenthesis at the end of that line. Once I add that, I get a plot that looks like what I'd expect.

Comment: Can the downvoters explain their downvotes?

Comment: Sure. I downvoted because after switching between reproducible and non-reproducible questions (which makes it hard for folks answering), what you've settled on seems like it might just be a missing parenthesis. There isn't evidence of much research here—even with the post you link to, you just said "it isn't working," which doesn't help folks help you debug. Take a look back through [ask] and the link in the 1st comment for advice on asking a question that is easy to answer and helpful for future site users

Comment: I see. Thank you, I get that I should have researched more.

Answer (score 1):

are you talking about coord_flip()? This will turn your chart 90 degrees

EDITED, Added below:

Try this below

```
  ggplot(data=mpg)+
    geom_bar(mapping=aes(x=model, y=..prop.., group=1))
```

Comment: No I am not. Basically, instead of count on the vertical axis, I want proportions.

Comment: see my code in my above answer. "..prop.." will plot the proportions on the y-axis for your x-axis variables. Cheers!

Comment: Excellent. Is there any way to show all percentages between 10 and 100, and to write them as percentages rather than decimals?

Comment: Also, I don't understand the use of group. I've tried to look it up in RStudio, but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a data frame containing the proportions first, then use `stat = "identity"`.

```r
library(tidyverse)

mtcars %>% 
  as_tibble %>% 
  group_by(cyl) %>% 
  summarize(prop = n()/nrow(.)) %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_bar(aes(cyl, prop), stat = "identity")
```

Comment: you don't need to create a whole new dataframe. Just change to "y=..prop..". See my answer.

Comment: You are right, I didn't read your code after you talked about `coord_flip()`, which OP clearly did not ask for

Comment: @Schilker you don't *need* to do the aggregation yourself beforehand, but it's often a good idea since it gives you better control than ggplot alone provides

Comment: I agree @shs, less is more IMHO